# WPF Binding Property not found

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, binding, itemscontrol

I have problem with binding.

This line: `Center="{Binding Position, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`
causes a problem at runtime. It gives me this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'Position' property not found on 'object' ''ContentPresenter'
>   (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Position;
>   DataItem='ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target element is
>   'EllipseGeometry' (HashCode=63639374); target property is 'Center'
>   (type 'Point')

This is my model:

```
public interface IRadarReader
{
    BindingList<RadarEntity> Entities { get; }
    RadarEntity LocalPlayer { get; }
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public class RadarEntity
{
    public Point Position { get; set; }
    public PlayerTeam Team { get; set; }
    public EntityType Type { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using System.Windows.Point for Position.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSGOHack.GUI"
    x:Class="Game.GUI.MainWindow"
    Title="Game Tool" Height="334" Width="415"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<Window.Resources>
    <l:RadarTeamToColorConverter x:Key="RadarTeamToColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Radar">
        <Viewbox>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GameReader.RadarReader.Entities}" Background="#FFA4D16E">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Width="100" Height="100"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Path Fill="{Binding Team, Converter={StaticResource RadarTeamToColorConverter}}">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <EllipseGeometry x:Name="PlayerEllipse"
                                    Center="{Binding Position, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    RadiusX="5"
                                    RadiusY="5"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Viewbox>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

In Snoop 2.8.0 I can see that rest of things are binded correctly. Value converter is working. Only this "Position" property is highlighted red with errors in Snoop.

Where is error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{TemplatedParent}` wont work because that resolves to `ContentPresenter` as you read from the error. If you're interested why, you should really inspect visual tree with Snoop.

<s>However, I doub't that @Hamlet answer works. The `EllipseGeometry` element does not inherit the `DataContext`. **The `EllipseGeometry` element is NOT in the visual tree.**</s>

You could try this:

```
Center="{Binding DataContext.Position, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Comment: Hamlets anser kind of works. I'm not getting this error and I can see canvas outline in snoop but no ellipses are displayed.

Comment: @Hooch: you should change the `Stroke` property of `Path` too. I'll have to check into this - I am gettig myself confused with this visual tree concept :p, ps, does the binding really read the `Position` property? Put breakpoint on getter. That's the reliable way if binding really works.

Comment: I found that my Binding with converter is not working. My Converter returns System.Media.Colors. If I put color by hand it works.

Comment: @Hooch: the Converer is supposed to return `Brush`. Try `new SolidColorBrush(..)`

Answer (score 1):

Why you bind to temptated parent? This should work.

```
<Path.Data>
    <EllipseGeometry x:Name="PlayerEllipse"
                Center="{Binding Position}"
                RadiusX="5"
                RadiusY="5"/>
</Path.Data>
```

Comment: It is not giving me that error now. I added it as a "possible" fix. Thanks I'm not getting this error anymore. But for some reason no ellipses are displayed.